# How to put an icon to system status bar with Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I need to put an app icon to the system status bar (on top) on `iOS` and `Android` with `Cordova` (like the clock icon when you set an alarm). Is there any plugin available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android on the status bar you cannot add icons to the right (system icons) as this is reserved for system. You're not system, therefore you should not be on the status status bar. However; you can post on the left side (which is where app icons show up). Also even *if* you were system, unless you can modify the source code of the platform... this cannot be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to customize the system status bar on iOS.
You can manage to add a **widgets** instead.