# cordova - image in status bar

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, statusbar

is it possible to have an image behind the status bar in a Cordova App using Ionic and the status bar plugin like the image below? I can't find anything related to this:

[image: sta]

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**
My current screen:

[image]

My code:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-img src="https://i.imgur.com/whAtFTP.png" alt="Weeder start page image"></ion-img>

  <ion-grid>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <div class="ion-text-center ion-margin-vertical">
          <p class="slogan">
            Wherever you want,
            <br>
            whenever you want.
          </p>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
          <ion-button color="primary" expand="block">Log in</ion-button>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col>
          <ion-button color="secondary" expand="block" (click)="register()">Sign up</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <div class="ion-text-center ion-no-margin ion-margin-top">
          <ion-text color="secondary" class="copyright">
            &copy; Weeder
          </ion-text>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39421708/how-to-put-an-icon-to-system-status-bar-with-cordova

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Transparent status bar:

this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);

this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#D9FFFFFF');

Transparent ARGB hex [value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28481374/7456041)

- App under [status bar](https://github.com/UlisesCeca/cordova-plugin-fullscreen.git#3eba6c2b9ccc96e14c3b178ef781111557b47024)

  ```
  AndroidFullScreen.showUnderStatusBar(successFunction, errorFunction);
  ```